# How to change the name/label to delete objects in the change list page in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django and I want to change the name/label with which the delete action appears in the change list page in Django admin as shown in the pic :

[image]

my admin.py file looks like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_list_template='change_list_form.html'

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So is there any way to change it or is it permanent??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it can be changed.

And to do that add the following code to your admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected

delete_selected.short_description = 'Type here your new name/label for the delete action'
```

And after adding this your admin.py file your admin.py file should look like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected

delete_selected.short_description = 'Type here your new name/label for the delete action'


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_list_template='change_list_form.html'

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

That's all you have to do.